# How to boot AOSP 11 via U-Boot (RK3566/Quartz64-A)?

Tags: embedded-linux, android-source, u-boot, rockchip

I'm trying to boot Android 11 using U-Boot and it's not decompressing the kernel image.

My bootcommand is as follows:

`echo Starting AOSP boot sequence && env set devnum 0 && mmc dev $devnum && echo Reading boot... && part start mmc $devnum boot boot_start && part size mmc $devnum boot boot_size && mmc read $loadaddr $boot_start $boot_size && echo Reading dtbo... && abootimg get dtb_load_addr dtboaddr && part start mmc $devnum dtbo dtbo_start && part size mmc $devnum dtbo dtbo_size && mmc read $dtboaddr $dtbo_start $dtbo_size && echo Copying dtb... && abootimg get dtb --index=0 dtb0_start dtb0_size && env set fdtaddr 0x600000 && cp.b $dtb0_start $fdtaddr $dtb0_size && echo Merging DTB... && fdt addr $fdtaddr 0x100000 && adtimg addr $dtboaddr && adtimg get dt --index=0 dtbo0_addr && fdt apply $dtbo0_addr && echo Booting AOSP... && bootm $loadaddr $loadaddr $fdtaddr`

Here is the same broken up into multiple lines (for readability sake):

```
echo Starting AOSP boot sequence
env set devnum 0
mmc dev $devnum

echo Reading boot...
part start mmc $devnum boot boot_start
part size mmc $devnum boot boot_size
mmc read $loadaddr $boot_start $boot_size

echo Reading dtbo...
abootimg get dtb_load_addr dtboaddr
part start mmc $devnum dtbo dtbo_start
part size mmc $devnum dtbo dtbo_size
mmc read $dtboaddr $dtbo_start $dtbo_size

echo Copying dtb...
abootimg get dtb --index=0 dtb0_start dtb0_size
env set fdtaddr 0x600000
cp.b $dtb0_start $fdtaddr $dtb0_size

echo Merging DTB...
fdt addr $fdtaddr 0x100000
adtimg addr $dtboaddr
adtimg get dt --index=0 dtbo0_addr
fdt apply $dtbo0_addr

echo Booting AOSP...
bootm $loadaddr $loadaddr $fdtaddr
```

I basically followed the guide [here](https://u-boot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/android/boot-image.html#dtb-and-dtbo-blobs), adding missing bits and pieces as needed.

The log prints as follows (serial console):

```
...memory initialization omitted for brevity...

U-Boot SPL 2023.10-aosp-00615-gd1c943e343 (Nov 06 2023 - 21:59:41 +0100)
Trying to boot from MMC1
## Checking hash(es) for config config-1 ... OK
## Checking hash(es) for Image atf-1 ... sha256+ OK
## Checking hash(es) for Image u-boot ... sha256+ OK
## Checking hash(es) for Image fdt-1 ... sha256+ OK
## Checking hash(es) for Image atf-2 ... sha256+ OK
## Checking hash(es) for Image atf-3 ... sha256+ OK
## Checking hash(es) for Image atf-4 ... sha256+ OK
## Checking hash(es) for Image atf-5 ... sha256+ OK
## Checking hash(es) for Image atf-6 ... sha256+ OK
INFO:    Preloader serial: 2
NOTICE:  BL31: v2.3():v2.3-607-gbf602aff1:cl
NOTICE:  BL31: Built : 10:16:03, Jun  5 2023
INFO:    GICv3 without legacy support detected.
INFO:    ARM GICv3 driver initialized in EL3
INFO:    pmu v1 is valid 220114
INFO:    dfs DDR fsp_param[0].freq_mhz= 1056MHz
INFO:    dfs DDR fsp_param[1].freq_mhz= 324MHz
INFO:    dfs DDR fsp_param[2].freq_mhz= 528MHz
INFO:    dfs DDR fsp_param[3].freq_mhz= 780MHz
INFO:    Using opteed sec cpu_context!
INFO:    boot cpu mask: 0
INFO:    BL31: Initializing runtime services
WARNING: No OPTEE provided by BL2 boot loader, Booting device without OPTEE initialization. SMC`s destined for OPTEE will return SMC_UNK
ERROR:   Error initializing runtime service opteed_fast
INFO:    BL31: Preparing for EL3 exit to normal world
INFO:    Entry point address = 0xa00000
INFO:    SPSR = 0x3c9


U-Boot 2023.10-aosp-00615-gd1c943e343 (Nov 06 2023 - 23:32:08 +0100)

Model: Pine64 RK3566 Quartz64-A Board
DRAM:  8 GiB (effective 7.7 GiB)
PMIC:  RK8170 (on=0x40, off=0x00)
Core:  307 devices, 23 uclasses, devicetree: separate
MMC:   mmc@fe2b0000: 1, mmc@fe2c0000: 2, mmc@fe310000: 0
Loading Environment from nowhere... OK
In:    serial@fe660000
Out:   serial@fe660000
Err:   serial@fe660000
Model: Pine64 RK3566 Quartz64-A Board
rockchip_dnl_key_pressed: no saradc device found
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
Starting AOSP boot sequence
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0(part 0) is current device
Reading boot...

MMC read: dev # 0, block # 32768, count 65536 ... 65536 blocks read: OK
Reading dtbo...

MMC read: dev # 0, block # 98304, count 16384 ... 16384 blocks read: OK
Copying dtb...
Merging DTB...
Working FDT set to 600000
0x22f (559)
Booting AOSP...
## Booting Android Image at 0x00c00800 ...
Kernel load addr 0x00c01000 size 15184 KiB
Kernel command line: console=ttyS2,1500000 earlycon=uart8250,mmio32,0xfe660000 androidboot.selinux=permissive service_locator.enable=1 kpti=0 loop.max_part=7 firmware_class.path=/vendor/etc/firmware buildvariant=user
RAM disk load addr 0x01ad5000 size 751 KiB
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 00600000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x600000
Working FDT set to 600000
   Uncompressing Kernel Image
lz4 compressed: uncompress error -71
Must RESET board to recover
=>
```

Can anyone provide some guidance on how to boot Android Boot Images (v2) using U-Boot?
The boot image is located on eMMC and U-Boot is able to read the DTB:

```
U-Boot 2023.10-aosp-00615-gd1c943e343 (Nov 06 2023 - 22:16:45 +0100)

Model: Pine64 RK3566 Quartz64-A Board
DRAM:  8 GiB (effective 7.7 GiB)
PMIC:  RK8170 (on=0x40, off=0x00)
Core:  307 devices, 23 uclasses, devicetree: separate
MMC:   mmc@fe2b0000: 1, mmc@fe2c0000: 2, mmc@fe310000: 0
Loading Environment from nowhere... OK
In:    serial@fe660000
Out:   serial@fe660000
Err:   serial@fe660000
Model: Pine64 RK3566 Quartz64-A Board
rockchip_dnl_key_pressed: no saradc device found
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
=> env set devnum 0
=> mmc dev $devnum
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0(part 0) is current device
=> part start mmc $devnum boot boot_start
=> part size mmc $devnum boot boot_size
=> mmc read $loadaddr $boot_start $boot_size

MMC read: dev # 0, block # 32768, count 65536 ... 65536 blocks read: OK
=> abootimg get dtb_load_addr dtboaddr
=> echo $dtboaddr
11f00000
=> abootimg help 
abootimg - manipulate Android Boot Image

Usage:
abootimg addr <boot_img_addr> [<vendor_boot_img_addr>]>
    - set the address in RAM where boot image is located
      ($loadaddr is used by default)
abootimg dump dtb
    - print info for all DT blobs in DTB area
abootimg get ver [varname]
    - get header version
abootimg get recovery_dtbo [addr_var [size_var]]
    - get address and size (hex) of recovery DTBO area in the image
      [addr_var]: variable name to contain DTBO area address
      [size_var]: variable name to contain DTBO area size
abootimg get dtb_load_addr [varname]
    - get load address (hex) of DTB, from image header
abootimg get dtb --index=<num> [addr_var [size_var]]
    - get address and size (hex) of DT blob in the image by index
      <num>: index number of desired DT blob in DTB area
      [addr_var]: variable name to contain DT blob address
      [size_var]: variable name to contain DT blob size
=> abootimg dump dtb
## DTB area contents (concat format):
 - DTB #0:
           (DTB)size = 89040
          (DTB)model = Rockchip PX30 AD D6 board
     (DTB)compatible = rockchip,px30-ad-d6
 - DTB #1:
           (DTB)size = 89498
          (DTB)model = Rockchip PX30 AD R35 MB board
     (DTB)compatible = rockchip,px30-ad-r35-mb
 - DTB #2:
           (DTB)size = 91054
          (DTB)model = Rockchip PX30 AD R35 MB board
     (DTB)compatible = rockchip,px30-ad-r35-mb
 - DTB #3:
           (DTB)size = 88737
          (DTB)model = Rockchip PX30 AD R35 MB board
     (DTB)compatible = rockchip,px30-ad-r35-mb
...omitted for brevity...
 - DTB #114:
           (DTB)size = 116053
          (DTB)model = Rockchip RK3568 NVR DEMO DDR4 V12 Linux SPI NAND Board
     (DTB)compatible = rockchip,rk3568-nvr-demo-ddr4-v12-linux-spi-nand
 - DTB #115:
           (DTB)size = 116029
          (DTB)model = Rockchip RK3568 NVR DEMO DDR4 V12 Linux Board
     (DTB)compatible = rockchip,rk3568-nvr-demo-ddr4-v12-linux
 - DTB #116:
           (DTB)size = 111760
          (DTB)model = Rockchip RK3568J CORE DDR4 V10 Board
     (DTB)compatible = rockchip,rk3568j-core-ddr4-v10
 - DTB #117:
           (DTB)size = 118858
          (DTB)model = Rockchip RK630 RK3568 DDR3 V10 Board
     (DTB)compatible = rockchip,rk630-rk3568-ddr3-v10
```

**EDIT:** The kernel starts booting when not compressed (all CONFIG_COMPRESS_* options set to n). I would still like to solve the decompression issue. Although the boot image size is not of concern to me since I can easily repartition the eMMC, I would still prefer to have compression enabled.

See:

```
U-Boot 2023.10-aosp-00615-gd1c943e343 (Nov 06 2023 - 23:32:08 +0100)

Model: Pine64 RK3566 Quartz64-A Board
DRAM:  8 GiB (effective 7.7 GiB)
PMIC:  RK8170 (on=0x40, off=0x00)
Core:  307 devices, 23 uclasses, devicetree: separate
MMC:   mmc@fe2b0000: 1, mmc@fe2c0000: 2, mmc@fe310000: 0
Loading Environment from nowhere... OK
In:    serial@fe660000
Out:   serial@fe660000
Err:   serial@fe660000
Model: Pine64 RK3566 Quartz64-A Board
rockchip_dnl_key_pressed: no saradc device found
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
Starting AOSP boot sequence
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0(part 0) is current device
Reading boot...

MMC read: dev # 0, block # 32768, count 98304 ... 98304 blocks read: OK
Reading dtbo...

MMC read: dev # 0, block # 131072, count 16384 ... 16384 blocks read: OK
Copying dtb...
Merging DTB...
Working FDT set to 600000
0x22f (559)
Booting AOSP...
## Booting Android Image at 0x00c00800 ...
Kernel load addr 0x00c01000 size 29319 KiB
Kernel command line: console=ttyS2,1500000 earlycon=uart8250,mmio32,0xfe660000 androidboot.selinux=permissive service_locator.enable=1 kpti=0 loop.max_part=7 firmware_class.path=/vendor/etc/firmware buildvariant=userdebug
RAM disk load addr 0x028a3000 size 890 KiB
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 00600000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x600000
Working FDT set to 600000
   XIP Kernel Image
   Loading Ramdisk to ede37000, end edf155c6 ... OK
ERROR: reserving fdt memory region failed (addr=0 size=0 flags=0)
   Loading Device Tree to 00000000edd34000, end 00000000ede36fff ... OK
Working FDT set to edd34000

Starting kernel ...

[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x412fd050]
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.19.154-xos (nobody@android-build) (Android (6877366 based on r383902b1) clang version 11.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project b397f81060ce6d701042b782172ed13bee898b79), GNU ld (binutils-2.27-bd24d23f) 2.27.0.20170315) #27 SMP PREEMPT Tue Nov 7 18:37:58 CET 2023
```